# What is the true value of $A(\lnot\varphi)$ in $A(\lnot\varphi\rightarrow(\theta\land\lnot\theta))=1$

Tags: propositional-calculus

$A(\lnot\varphi\rightarrow(\theta\land\lnot\theta))=1$

I know $(\theta\land\lnot\theta)$ is a falsehood. Can I say $A(\lnot\varphi)=1$? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We map **T** on $1$ and **F** on $0$.

As you correctly say : $\theta \land \lnot \theta$ is always **F** (it is a *contradiction*) and thus $A(\theta \land \lnot \theta)=0$.

We have to consider the truth table for the [logical conncetive $\to$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication):

> in order that $p \to $ **F** is **T** we need that $p$ is **F**.

Thus, in order that $A(¬φ→(θ∧¬θ))=1$ we need that $A(\lnot \varphi)=0$ [ $\lnot \varphi$ must be **F** ], and thus $A(\varphi)=1$ [ i.e. $\varphi$ must be **T**].

Comment: Oh, wait. Why $A(θ∧¬θ)=0$? Isn't the truth value depends on the truth assignment?

Comment: @yashirq - you have only to try ... Two cases : $A : A(\theta)=1$ and $A' : A'(\theta)=0$.